# Migration request: 'What are the aspects associated with working in a 'liberal arts environment'?'

Tags: support, migration

I would like to request that this question be moved back to the academic stack exchange. This is a question related to an academic job search, and I really would like to hear from people in academia, not from professionals working at private companies. I am unclear why it was moved in the first place since I have asked a lot of job-related questions at the academia stack exchange before with very good results.

I am happy to alter the question so as to better fit the academic stack exchange.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9927/what-are-the-aspects-associated-with-working-in-a-liberal-arts-environment

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if you think it was a bad migration. This question has nothing in it that indicates the individual is applying for a job in a school, or anything similar to that, other than working in a "liberal arts environment". This has nothing to do with a university of any sort; Apple Inc. is famous for their pushing of a liberal arts culture. As such, I interpreted this as a generic job search question, which is completely off-topic here. It didn't even occur to me that you were referring to working in a university.

If you wish to edit the question, feel free. I'm still not sure that it would be on-topic here, even with editing, as this site focuses mostly on research, but I'll leave that to you.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I honestly had no idea the phrase was so broad. I have clarified the question, please let me know if the narrower scope of the question warrants a re-migration. Thanks again.